# How to handle the "indentation hell" that Shiny's ui can become?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

Is it just me?, or somebody else out there is bothered by how the ubiquitous use of `...` in Shiny's api to build the ui can very quickly become an "indentation hell"? (paraphrasing Javascript's callback hell)

Consider this example. Let's say you decided to use `shinydashboard` to build a small app with a couple of columns? It would look something like this:

```
ui <- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "Dashboard Title"),

    dashboardSidebar(
        sidebarMenu(
            menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "dashboard"),
            menuItem("Widgets", tabName = "widgets")
        )
    ),

    dashboardBody(
        tabItems(
            tabItem(
                tabName = "dashboard",
                fluidRow(
                    column(
                        width = 3, 
                        valueBoxOutput("valuebox1", width = NULL),
                        valueBoxOutput("valuebox2", width = NULL)
                    ),
                    column(
                        width = 3, 
                        valueBoxOutput("valuebox1", width = NULL),
                        valueBoxOutput("valuebox2", width = NULL)
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Way too complex and uncomfortable to read (if and when you get the indentation right), isn't it?

Not to mention that you basically ran out of space to write the output function parameters, 'cause you will be dangerously close to the 80 characters margin.

How to make this example shwallower?, or how to handle this better?

Comment: There's absolutely no requirement to 'inline' every part of the UI. Esp. for separate tabs, I find it convenient to store their definitions in variables and insert where needed. Comment-sized example: `my_col = column(width=3,plotOutput("aplot"),...)` and then you can just use the handle like `basicPage(h2('bla'),my_col)`.

Comment: Making liberal use of modules will help a lot. You can break things into as many pieces as you want. It is also great for collaborating

Answer (score 1):

You may want to experiment with the `backpipe` package.

It inverts the magrittr `%>%` pipe by piping from right to left, like this `%<%`.

One of its selling points is:

> write clearer, more debuggable shinyUI code such that the order of code matches the HTML output.

`div() %<% p("This is some text")`

There are a few more examples on the [Github Page](https://github.com/decisionpatterns/backpipe) that show more complex indentation applications.